# How to add validation for checkboxes in JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a form like below and I want to add vaidation for JQuery, I tried using html required attribute but it is not working, help me in this

The code is

```
//question 1
<label class="container">
  <input class="chk check_answer1" type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value='1' required="required">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input class="chk check_answer1" type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value='1' required="required">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label><label class="container">
  <input class="chk check_answer1" type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value='1' required="required">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

//question 2
<label class="container">
  <input class="chk check_answer2" type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value='2' required="required">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input class="chk check_answer2" type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value='2' required="required">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label><label class="container">
  <input class="chk check_answer2" type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value='2' required="required">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

//question 3
<label class="container">
  <input class="chk check_answer3" type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value='3' required="required">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input class="chk check_answer3" type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value='3' required="required">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label><label class="container">
  <input class="chk check_answer3" type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value='3' required="required">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

This is the code and In this page the user has to  select atleast one option for every question

Comment: You have mixed quotes all over your code... For example `value='1"` must be opened and closed with the same quote standard. `value='1'` or `value="1"` looks like you're using double quotes in the majority of your previous code, I suggest fixing those typos.

Comment: You don't need to do `required="required"`, you just need to add `required` to the input. See the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_required).

Comment: @j-petty, Yes I tried only using required also, Still it didn't work

Comment: @dale landry, sorry It's my typo mistake here, In the code it was correct

Comment: You can also use HTML5 built in validation if you group all the inputs in a `form` element.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to name the grouped inputs that are alike the same name in your HTML. 
Use `.on(change function()` then locate the input (element) you're using, `$(this)` and get its name.
Then we write a conditional to see if it is checked, if so remove any other instances of a check from that `<input>` names group.

***EDIT:*** Function on each input to check the `onchange` and then if all instances of your inputs has one checked element we change the disabled attribute to false, unlocking the submit button.

You can add display messages if you like and css to the Jquery code by adding an empty `<div id="msg"></div>` where you want to display info, then call on the value of that div to place text there depending on the message you wish to convey.

```js
//--> Remove the code below if you do want the user to only select one option per 
//--> group and it is okay for them to select multiple options per group...

$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var th = $(this),
    name = th.prop('name');
  if (th.is(':checked')) {
    th.attr('checked', 'checked');
    $(':checkbox[name="' + name + '"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
  }
});

//--> This handles the locking of the submit button
function checkChecked(divId) {
  var oneOfEachChecked = false;
  $('#' + divId + ' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    if ($(".check_answer1").is(":checked") && $(".check_answer2").is(":checked") && $(".check_answer3").is(":checked")) {
      oneOfEachChecked = true;
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#mash').show().text(' <--- Mash me now, I am unlocked!').css('background', 'lightgreen');
    }
  });
  if (oneOfEachChecked === false) {
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#mash').show().text(' X Sorry no go! X').css('background', '#FA3300');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <div class="divs" id="check_answer1">
    //question 1
    <label class="container"></label>
    <input class="chk check_answer1" onchange="checkChecked('check_answer1')" type="checkbox" name="check_answer1" value="1">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>

    <label class="container"></label>
    <input class="chk check_answer1" onchange="checkChecked('check_answer1')" type="checkbox" name="check_answer1" value="1">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    <label class="container"></label>
    <input class="chk check_answer1" onchange="checkChecked('check_answer1')" type="checkbox" name="check_answer1" value="1">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="divs" id="check_answer2">
    //question 2
    <label class="container"></label>
    <input class="chk check_answer2" onchange="checkChecked('check_answer2')" type="checkbox" name="check_answer2" value="2">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>

    <label class="container"></label>
    <input class="chk check_answer2" onchange="checkChecked('check_answer2')" type="checkbox" name="check_answer2" value="2">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    <label class="container"></label>
    <input class="chk check_answer2" onchange="checkChecked('check_answer2')" type="checkbox" name="check_answer2" value="2">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="divs" id="check_answer3">
    //question 3
    <label class="container"></label>
    <input class="chk check_answer3" onchange="checkChecked('check_answer3')" type="checkbox" name="check_answer3" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>

    <label class="container"></label>
    <input class="chk check_answer3" onchange="checkChecked('check_answer3')" type="checkbox" name="check_answer3" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    <label class="container"></label>
    <input class="chk check_answer3" onchange="checkChecked('check_answer3')" type="checkbox" name="check_answer3" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>

  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" disabled><span id="mash"></span>
</form>
```